# Webpack 4 and Pug not showing images

Tags: webpack, pug-loader

I'm having problems with my configuration of webpack and pug. Images are not displaying ( I got a 404 error )

This is: webpack.common.js

```
const path = require("path");
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
    const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
    const __ROOT__ = process.cwd();
    
    const fs = require("fs");
    
let templates = [];
let dir = "src";
let files = fs.readdirSync(dir);

files.forEach((file) => {
  if (file.match(/\.pug$/)) {
    let filename = file.substring(0, file.length - 4);
    templates.push(
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: dir + "/" + filename + ".pug",
        filename: filename + ".html",
        hash: true,
      })
    );
  }
});

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__ROOT__, "src/js/index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__ROOT__, "build"),
    filename: "js/[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "js/[name].chunk.js",
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), ...templates],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "raw-loader" },
          {
            loader: "pug-html-loader",
            options: {
              pretty: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
            configFile: path.resolve(__ROOT__, "config/babel.config.js"),
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp|svg)$/i,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[path][name].[ext]",
          context: "src", // prevent display of src/ in filename
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

next file webpack.dev.js:

```
const {
  merge
} = require("webpack-merge");
const commonConfig = require("./webpack.config.common");

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./build",
    compress: true,
    port: 3001,
    overlay: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
    }, ],
    rules: [{
      test: /\.s[ac]ss$/, 
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    }, ],
  },
});
```

and finally the pug index page: I tried multiples url, none of them works.

```
html
  head
    title Webpack 4

  body
    h1 Project starter

    hr
    
    img(src='images/logo.png')
    img(src='./images/logo.png')
    img(src='../images/logo.png')
    img(src='../../images/logo.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

I replace this lines:

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "raw-loader" },
          {
            loader: "pug-html-loader",
            options: {
              pretty: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

with this lines and works fine:

```
rules: [{
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "html-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "pug-html-loader",
            options: {
              pretty: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```